# react native video fullscreen controll

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-video

I use in my app react-native-video.It works well but on android I don't have the fullscreen
control. Do I have to make a custom control or did I forget something?
There is my code for my player :

```
  <Video
      key={`player-${retryCount}`}
      ref={ref => {this._player = ref}}
      style={[styles.container, style, {height: this.state.height}]}
      paused={retryCount === 0}
      source={{uri: source.url}}
      progressUpdateInterval={3000}
      controls
      onError={ this._onError }
      onProgress={ this._onProgress }
      resizeMode={'stretch'}
      onLoad={this._setHeight}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls not available on android for react-native-video on full sceen so you have to make your own custom controls or can use these libs.

[react-native-video-player](https://github.com/cornedor/react-native-video-player)

[react-native-video-controls](https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls)

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: second library is helpful thanks for this